# positioning label node depending on slope of a edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, foreach

I am creating a set of nodes with a `foreach`. After that i am drawing a edge between them that should show a value in the middle above the line. Unfortunately there are some situations where the line passes through the value, in which case it should be shifted to the left or the right. I am trying to find a way to add a condition to the style of the node that depends on the slope of the edge but until now i didnt get lucky. My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \nodename/\xcor/\ycor in { A/1/1,  B/1/4,  C/4/1,  D/4/4}      
    \node (\nodename) at (\xcor,\ycor) [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick] {\textbf{\nodename}};

\foreach \from/\to/\lengthvalue in {A/B/1, A/C/2, A/D/3 }
    \draw  (\from) -- (\to) node[pos=0.5,above right] {\textbf{\lengthvalue}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

creates

[image]

I will always end up writing a number over a line. If I use `above` the line AB will be the one. Unfortunately `slope` is not an option here. Is there a way to use `above`,`above left`,`above right` conditionally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe option `auto` for the nodes helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \nodename/\xcor/\ycor in { A/1/1,  B/1/4,  C/4/1,  D/4/4}      
    \node (\nodename) at (\xcor,\ycor) [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick] {\textbf{\nodename}};

\foreach \from/\to/\lengthvalue in {A/B/1, A/C/2, A/D/3}{
    \draw  (\from) -- (\to) node[midway,auto=left] {\textbf{\lengthvalue}};}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with an additional node `E` at `(10,4.5)`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

May be not what you ask for, but seems simpler to me:

(What about rotation?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \nodename/\xcor/\ycor in { A/1/1,  B/1/4,  C/4/1,  D/4/4}      
    \node (\nodename) at (\xcor,\ycor) [circle,draw=black,fill=white,thick] {\textbf{\nodename}};

\foreach \from/\to/\lengthvalue in {A/B/1, A/C/2, A/D/3 }{
    \draw  (\from) -- (\to) node[midway,rotate around={10:(\from)},rotate=-10] {\textbf{\lengthvalue}};}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first rotation is about the starting point and the second just rotates the node about itself.

If needed conditionals are an option too (I would calculate the angle to do it)

Comment: PS: Included  `foreach`'s  body inside {} since I think is a good practice

Comment: not exactly what i need in this situation, but a great idea for another porblem i am faceing. Thanks for that and the good practice advice

Comment: Welcome... I would chose the same answer too.